# Несоотвествие изображения и его размера

Tags: c#, windows, picturebox, jpeg

Здравствуйте. Очень понравились мне картинки из Windows Spotlight и решил сделать программу на C#, которая бы доставала картинки из системной папки и была возможность их сохранить. Но тут есть проблема: в той папке есть изображения как для десктопа, так и для телефона и у них одинаковый размер (тоесть система видит их так)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при просмотре изображение выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот даже кусок кода, который применяет изображение на pictureBox

```
    private void SelectImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        Image selectedImage = images[listBox.SelectedIndex];

        if (selectedImage.Height > pictureBox1.Height)
        {
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = selectedImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост. Из за невнимательности, я перепутал ширину и высоту. А чтобы оно подстраивалось красиво в pictureBox, достаточно поставить режим Zoom.